# log4j2 syslog datagram size eceeds limit for UDP

Tags: udp, log4j2, syslog

I am using `UDP` in `log4j2 Syslog` appender, I have configured the appender progrmmatically, messages are being logged into console and syslog, it's working fine unless the message becomes larger than `65446` characters.

Is there any way in `Syslog` (`Log4j2`) for `UDP` to increase the limit size of message to be sent over network..

I would appreciate any kind of help....

The following is the error it throws-:

```
2017-08-10 14:12:21,321 main ERROR Unable to write to stream UDP:localhost:514 for appender Bill: org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error flushing stream UDP:localhost:514
2017-08-10 14:12:21,322 main ERROR An exception occurred processing Appender Bill org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error flushing stream UDP:localhost:514
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flushDestination(OutputStreamManager.java:272)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:228)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.write(OutputStreamManager.java:201)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.writeByteArrayToManager(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:186)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.SocketAppender.directEncodeEvent(SocketAppender.java:446)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.tryAppend(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:170)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractOutputStreamAppender.append(AbstractOutputStreamAppender.java:161)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:448)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:433)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:417)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:403)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:63)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.logMessage(Logger.java:146)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2091)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:1988)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1960)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.debug(AbstractLogger.java:311)
at Log4j2Example.main(Log4j2Example.java:81)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: The message is larger than the maximum supported by the underlying transport: Datagram send failed
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.socketSend(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Unknown Source)
at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.net.DatagramOutputStream.flush(DatagramOutputStream.java:103)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.flushDestination(OutputStreamManager.java:270)
... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UDP messages can only have a size of 65,507 bytes. Use a different transport layer if you need larger messages.

Comment: Or increase the size of the socket send buffer if it is < 65507.

Comment: @EJP: how should this help with UDP? There is a limit on the size of a UDP datagram.

Answer (score 0):

I had same exact error and I solved it using a custom JSONLayout provided here: https://github.com/vy/log4j2-logstash-layout.

I guess that this layout is less verbose than the standard one provided by log4j2.
So now I can send messages through UDP, even ones containing big stack traces.

So my log4j2.xml looks like:

```
<Socket name="Logstash" host="hostname" port="portnumber" protocol="UDP" immediateFlush="false" ignoreExceptions="true">
   <LogstashLayout dateTimeFormatPattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ" eventTemplateUri="classpath:LogstashJsonEventLayoutV1.json"                 prettyPrintEnabled="true" stackTraceEnabled="true" />
</Socket>
```